# Find the equation of the tangent to the graph of the function at the given value of $x$:

Tags: calculus

> Find the equation of the tangent to the graph of the function at the given value of $x$,
> $$f(x) = x/(x+3), x = -5.$$

My problem is that I do not know how to find the derivative using the power rule when there is a fraction in the equation.

Comment: Do you mean $x/(x+3)$? Because otherwise $f(x)=3, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes. Also, how did you bold the equation? I do not know how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: If you click on *Edit* you can edit your question and see the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ataraxia Why you want to apply the power rule?

Comment: @pawel I would like to find the derivative (the slope of the tangent) so I can find the equation of the tangent line when x is -5

Comment: @Ataraxia Yes but you have to apply the quotient rule and not the power rule

Comment: @pawel Thank you for the clarification. I will learn the quotient rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for a tangent line at a point $a$ is given by
$$t(x)=f'(a)\cdot(x-a)+f(a).$$

---

We have $f(x)=x/({x-3}).$ By the quotient rule we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{(x+3)^2}.$$

Now we just have to plug $-5$ in. $f(-5)=5/2$ and $f'(-5)=-3/4$. That means that the tangent line is
$$t(x)=3/4(x+5)+5/2=3/4x+25/4.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not know there was a quotient rule. I will learn it.

Comment: Oh, that is what the checkmark is for! Sure thing!